# How to convert character dates to R format

Tags: r, date

There are a few similar questions I've seen that attempt to answer this question, but none are quite right for my problem.

[Converting dates from excel to R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23037089/converting-dates-from-excel-to-r)

[How do I convert dates in this format to a date class in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167341/how-do-i-convert-dates-in-this-format-to-a-date-class-in-r)

I have dates:

```
dates <- c("16 Jan 63", "16 Jan 73", "17 Jul 62", "25 Aug 60")
```

all years begin with "19-"

The obvious solution I thought to use was the `as.Date`, or `strptime` functions:

```
dates <- as.Date(dates, "%d %b %y")
dates
[1] "2063-01-16" "2073-01-16" "2062-07-17" "2060-08-25"
```

As you can see, the problem is with the year, none are correctly converted.

My next solution was to use `strsplit`:

```
dates <- c("16 Jan 63", "16 Jan 73", "17 Jul 62", "25 Aug 60")
new.dates <-  strsplit(dates, " ")
new.dates
[[1]]
[1] "16"  "Jan" "63" 

[[2]]
[1] "16"  "Jan" "73" 
# etc
```

However the problem begins when I try to paste "19" in front of the year, and then collapse them back into the same character.

```
new.dates[?] <- paste0("19", new.dates[?])
new.dates[?] <- paste(new.dates[?], collapse = " ")
```

I have no idea what the dimensions are supposed to be for pasting.  Eventually I want to format the dates using:

```
new.dates <- strptime(new.dates, "%d %b %Y")
new.dates <- as.Date(new.dates)
```

If anyone has any suggestions on how to do this, or a link to an already answered question, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could do `as.Date(dates, "%d %b %Y") + lubridate::years(1900)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try

```
as.Date(format(as.Date(dates,"%d %B %y"), "19%y-%m-%d"))
```